# using X509Certificate from KeyChain in OKHttpClient sslSocketFactory

Tags: java, android, x509certificate, keychain

I'm an Android Developer who has to use `KeyChain` not `KeyStore`. The KeyStore variant of our code works. I need to add `KeyChain` equivalent.

this works

```
  final char[] PASSWORD = "***SOMEPASSWORD****".toCharArray();
  TrustManager[] trustManager;
  SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;
  KeyStore keyStore;

  InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().getAssets().open("xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx.pfx");
  keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
  keyStore.load(inputStream,PASSWORD);
  TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance (TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
  trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
  TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
  if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager))
  {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:"
      + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
  }
  trustManager = trustManagers;

  KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
  keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore,PASSWORD);
  SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
  sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(),null,null);
  sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();


  OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).cookieJar(new ReactCookieJarContainer());
  builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustManager[0]);

  OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
```

The problem is this line `InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().getAssets().open("xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx.pfx");` we're not allowed to use the assets folder (for reasons outside the scope of this conversation) but we are allowed to put the self same file in the `KeyChain` so I did, and I can retrieve it using the following. `X509Certificate[] chain = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(context, "xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx");`

so since

```
   X509Certificate[] chain = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(context, "xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx"); //this gets the correct X509Certificate
```

Gets the certificate via `KeyChain` my instinct was to swap it out with this:

```
   X509TrustManager customTm = new X509TrustManager() {
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {

    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {

    }

    @Override
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
      try {
        return X509Certificate[] chain = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(context, "xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx");
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (KeyChainException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
  TrustManager[] trustManager = new TrustManager[] { customTm };
  sslContext.init(null, trustManager, null);
```

but it doesn't work, so my question is: **How do I use the X509Certificate I have from the `KeyChain` as a drop in replacement to the asset I pulled into the `KeyStore`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out, the code needs to become slightly different, but this wasn't documented anywhere I could find: I had to literally face roll the keyboard to get it done

so. the OP example was me using the pfx file in the assets folder.

[image]

In order to ***not*** use a from an asset file in the build environment (aka `KeyStore`), in order to load the cert direcly from a part of android OS at run time and get at it in code (aka `KeyChain`)(i.e. in order to load the cert you can see in the screen below on the device) ....

**THIS IS AN illustration of where it is in android, BUT NOT MY SCREEN SHOT** [image]

...use this code

```
final char[] PASSWORD = "***SOMEPASSWORD****".toCharArray();
TrustManager[] trustManager;
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;
KeyStore keyStore;

X509Certificate[] keychain;  
PrivateKey privateKey;   
keychain = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(context, "xkeyx-xaliasxx");
privateKey = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(context, "xkeyx-xaliasxx"); 
keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
keyStore.load(null, null);
keyStore.setKeyEntry("xkeyx-xaliasxx", privateKey, PASSWORD, keychain);  
TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance (TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
if (trustManagers.length != 1 || !(trustManagers[0] instanceof X509TrustManager))
  {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected default trust managers:"
      + Arrays.toString(trustManagers));
  }
trustManager = trustManagers;

KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore,PASSWORD);
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(),null,null);
sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();


OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).cookieJar(new ReactCookieJarContainer());
builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager) trustManager[0]);

OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
```

**NOTE this will only work AFTER the user in app has confirmed the certificate: so this code needs to have been run at least ONCE**

[image]

```
KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(RN.getReactActivity(), (KeyChainAliasCallback) alias -> {
Log.d("cert", String.format("User has selected client certificate alias: %s should be xkeyx-xaliasxx", alias));
 X509Certificate[] truechain;
 try {
    truechain = KeyChain.getCertificateChain(Context, alias);
    if (truechain != null) {
        Log.d("cert", "truechain count" + truechain.length);
    }
    else{
        Log.d("cert", "truechain count is null");
    }
 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
     Log.e("cert", "InterruptedException", e);
 } catch (KeyChainException e) {
     Log.e("cert", "KeyChainException", e);
 }
}, null, null, null, -1, null);
```

Comment: note this example can be used as either part of a `OkHttpClientFactory` implementation (where an alternate `OkHttpClient` is returned in `createNewNetworkModule` - referenced in `MainApplication.java` as `OkHttpClientProvider.setOkHttpClientFactory()`) or do it `JIT` with `NetworkingModule.setCustomClientBuilder()` as an `NetworkingModule.CustomClientBuilder` implementation